# Custom filter not working with elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, shopware6

I created a custom filter where I select only products that have a discounted price. I use the data stored in the database in the `product.price.percentage.net` field. If the system uses a mysql database, there is no problem - everything works as expected. The problem starts after switching to elasticsearch. In the query, I see a fragment responsible for filtering by this field. It looks like this:

```
"post_filter": {
    "bool": {
        "filter": [
            {
                "bool": {
                    "must": [
                        {
                            "term": {
                                "available": true
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "range": {
                                "price.percentage.c_b7d2554b0ce847cd82f3ac9bd1c0dfca.net": {
                                    "gt": 0
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        ]
    }
},
```

there is no error on the es side. As far as I can see, the path `price.percentage.c_b7d2554b0ce847cd82f3ac9bd1c0dfca.net` contains the currency id in it. I tried changing it to every currency I have in the system, but no results.

```
'dynamic_templates' => [
    [
        'cheapest_price' => [
            'match' => 'cheapest_price_rule*',
            'mapping' => ['type' => 'double'],
        ],
    ],
    [
        'price_percentage' => [
            'path_match' => 'price.*.percentage.*',
            'mapping' => ['type' => 'double'],
        ],
    ],
    [
        'long_to_double' => [
            'match_mapping_type' => 'long',
            'mapping' => ['type' => 'double'],
        ],
    ],
],
```

Unfortunately, I am fairly new to ES and have no idea how to approach the exact data contained in the indexes. I am using a google chrome plugin called `Multi Elasticsearch Head` and I can only see basic data like `id` and `fullText` there. There are also filters on the left side, but there I don't see anything related to price.

Do I need to do anything else to make it work on the ES side? Or maybe I made a mistake somewhere? I know that you can add data from ES (https://developer.shopware.com/docs/guides/plugins/plugins/elasticsearch/add-product-entity-extension-to-elasticsearch.html), but here this data should already be there.